# Accessing notifications on Windows 10 mobile from code

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-10

Is there a way on Windows 10 Mobile to grab notifications of other apps from my app  ? I know this is not possible on Windows Phone 8.1, is there a specification of some sort were I can read about it ?

Comment: Have you checked the official docs (MSDN)?

Comment: Googled for hours and hours over and over again. Nothing, I am afraid.

Comment: I think that would be a security issue if you could just read any notification. Doubt this is (oficially) possible :|

Comment: Please send me a link to the Windows 10 Mobile docs, btw.